# How is the space complexity of the following algorithm O(logn)?

Tags: python, algorithm

The following is a python code to find sum of list of elements using binary recursion from the book Goodrich and Tamassia.

```
    def binary_sum(S, start, stop):
  """Return the sum of the numbers in implicit slice S[start:stop]."""
        if start >= stop:                      # zero elements in slice
            return 0
        elif start == stop-1:                  # one element in slice
            return S[start]
        else:                                  # two or more elements in slice
            mid = (start + stop) // 2
            return binary_sum(S, start, mid) + binary_sum(S, mid, stop)
```

So it is stated in the book that:

"The size of the range is divided in half at each recursive call, and
so the depth of the recursion is 1+logn. Therefore, binary sum uses O(logn)
amount of additional space. However, the running time of
binary sum is O(n), as there are 2n−1 function calls, each requiring constant time."

From what I understand it is saying that the space complexity of the algorithm is O(logn). But since it is making 2n-1 function calls, wouldn't python have to keep 2n-1 different activation records for each function? And therefore, the space complexity should be O(n). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good explanation of this question on  [Space complexity analysis of binary recursive sum algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29134/space-complexity-analysis-of-binary-recursive-sum-algorithm)

The space complexity of a recursive algorithm depends on the depth of the recursion which is log(n)

> Why does the depth of recursion affect the space, required by an
>   algorithm? Each recursive function call usually needs to allocate some
>   additional memory (for temporary data) to process its arguments. At
>   least, each such a call has to store some information about its parent
>   call - just to know where to return after finishing. Let's imagine you
>   are performing a task, and you need to perform a sub-task *inside*
>   this first task - so you need to remember (or write down on a paper)
>   where you stopped in the first task to be able to continue it after
>   you finish the sub-task. And so on, sub-sub-task inside a sub-task...
>   So, a recursive algorithm will require space `O(depth of recursion)`.

Answer (score 1):

> it is making 2n-1 function calls

Not all of them at the same time. A function call has a beginning and an end.

> wouldn't python have to keep 2n-1 different activation records for each function?

Only active activation records need to occupy space. There are O(recursion_depth) of those at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

space complexity of any algorithm not depends on the no. of function calls. It depends on the depth of the recursion. In the above algorithm the depth of the recursion is O(log n).

Comment: Space complexity depends on the depth of recursion AND on the amount of extra space that you take, even without recursion (e.g. extra variables needed)